# RPXNOW without refreshing

Tags: javascript, iframe, rpxnow

Is it possible to use rpx_now without refreshing the whole page after authenticated?

I want to use the rpx_now in the widget like uservoice. User can click the widget everywhere in the website, see something in a popup iframe, user should do everything in the popup iframe including login. I found rpx_now was always refreshing the whole page, but I only want to refresh the popup iframe. Do you know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do what you want to do with the default out-of-the-box widget.  However, you can use the RPX capabilities in a completely custom solution that would allow you to do what you want to do.  In RPXNow, when you click on the "Quick Start Guide" there are three tabs: Popup, Embed, and Custom Interface.  Use the custom interface option to create your own solution.  This will take a fair amount of development, but you can create the experience you want in a fairly straightforward manner.

John Beutler
Solution Engineer
JanRain, Inc.